# Global date/boolean formatting in frontend of JSF application

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am developing a JSF dashboard web application which includes several very large PrimeFaces datatables. It would be really handy if I could set a global format for the representation of certain types – currently the only way I can think of is having backing bean methods like

```
public String formattedBoolean(Boolean inputBoolean) {
    return inputBoolean ? "Yes" : "No";
}
```

which I could then manually call from the frontend (and similarly, I could use `f:convertDateTime` components for formatting date objects as string). However, this type of approach would require adding a lot of boilerplate XHTML, such as

```
<p:column headerText="Start Date" id="startDate"
                        sortBy="#{dataContainer.startDate}"
                        filterBy="#{dataContainer.startDate}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{dataContainer.startDate}">
                            <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                        </h:outputText>
</p:column>
```

which I'd rather avoid. Does anyone know if there is a more elegant way of globally overriding the default Java string representation of objects in the frontend, or at least within the context of a data table?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311664/override-default-converter-in-jsf

Comment: @JasperdeVries: sorry, looked at the wrong tab in my browser... Yes overriding the default converter is a good way here. Or a combination...

Comment: From the performance perspective, it would be MUCH better to use a custom facelets function and just do:

<span>#{myLib:myFunction(dataContainer.startDate)}</span>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31690332/overriding-the-jsf-converter-javax-faces-convert-bigdecimalconverter-in-favor-of

Comment: @tandraschko: why not override the default converter? It makes it happen automatically everywhere? (Yes, tagfile is not the best I agree)

Comment: I didn't say that this is not a good solution, i just say that there is better one for performance :D

Answer (score 0):

Following advice above, I have decided to override the default FacesConverter for the given classes, as these are formats I'd want to present consistently in text throughout the application.